# Matching URL with wildcards

Tags: javascript, regex, url, wildcard

I'm trying to match URLs with wildcards in them to actual URLs. For example:

```
http://*google.com/*
```

Needs to match

```
http://maps.google.com
```

And

```
http://www.google.com/maps
```

What would be the best way of going about this?

I've tried using a regular expression and that works fine when I manually program it but I'm not sure whether it's possible to dynamically generate regular expressions or if that would be the best practice in this situation.

```
/(http|https):\/\/.*\.?google\.com\/?.*/i
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: Watchout for the issue pointed out by @Sjoerd

Comment: What was your solution to this, @sam-bowler?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Replace all occurrences of `*` in the pattern with `[^ ]*` - it matches a sequence of zero or more non-space characters.

Thus `http://*google.com/*` will become `http://[^ ]*google.com/[^ ]*`

Here is a regular expression to do the task:

```
regex = urlPattern.replace(/\*/g, "[^ ]*");
```

Comment: this is genious!

Comment: Clever and effective. Nice.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see a well tested library for extracting parts of a URI, I would check out Google Closure Library's goog.uri.utils methods.

https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/8e44fb343fff467938f9476ba7f727c6acac76d8/closure/goog/uri/utils.js#L187

Here's the regex that does the heavy lifting:

```
goog.uri.utils.splitRe_ = new RegExp(
    '^' +
    '(?:' +
      '([^:/?#.]+)' +                     // scheme - ignore special characters
                                          // used by other URL parts such as :,
                                          // ?, /, #, and .
    ':)?' +
    '(?://' +
      '(?:([^/?#]*)@)?' +                 // userInfo
      '([\\w\\d\\-\\u0100-\\uffff.%]*)' + // domain - restrict to letters,
                                          // digits, dashes, dots, percent
                                          // escapes, and unicode characters.
      '(?::([0-9]+))?' +                  // port
    ')?' +
    '([^?#]+)?' +                         // path
    '(?:\\?([^#]*))?' +                   // query
    '(?:#(.*))?' +                        // fragment
    '$');
```