# How to Validating custom url in javascript using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am in need to validate a url like

http://www.abc.com/mytester/*

if **/mytester/*** is in the URL right after abc.com/, then I want to include another javascript code, otherwise second js code.

How can i write this in javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching URL with wildcards](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117218/matching-url-with-wildcards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex: `/mytester/$` will make sure that `/mytester/` is at the very end of the string. Should, for instance, the url be `http://www.abc.com/mytester/abc` the regex will fail.

EDIT:

Assuming that you will always have a full URL, (one starting with `http://www`), you can use this regex: `^http://www.abc.com/mytester/`. This will expect to start matching the URL from the very beginning of the string. It does not care what follows after the last `/`, as long as the URL starts with `http://www.abc.com/mytester/`.